# XAMPP Tomcat - GET request doesnt work, HTTP 404

Tags: tomcat, xampp

I've got XAMPP 1.8.3 with Tomcat 7.

My app starts fine, but when I sending GET-request to the server, request doesnt work, I catch HttpResponseException.

That's what Tomcat saying - localhost_access_log:

```
[12/Nov/2014:14:14:49 +0900] "GET /MyApp/chat?name=Alex HTTP/1.1" 404 1009
```

How can i solve it?

Previously I've tested this app on Tomcat in Eclipse. All work's fine. Same app, all tomcat configurations what I know are the same.

Comment: Thats a log information from the Apache web server not from Tomcat. Try port 8080 in your url.

Comment: I have a port in url, server.xml have same port config.